# jsp buttons through out.println

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I have a jsp file and using java i am adding html code to it through the use of out.println

there is a <button onclick = <% ( java function )%>

however when running button shows and everything just doesnt run java code

but when adding button code directly to jsp without using out.println works.

(this is not possible to add the html code directly to jsp file.

ive tried using the <% %> tag for inputting in java
tried to use javascript but couldnt use function( p1) cause p1 is in the form of java string and vice versa
jsp file:

```html
        <div class="container">
        <div class="menu">
            <h2 class="menu-group-heading">pizza</h2>
            <div class="menu-group">
                <%
                out.println(Menu.getMenu("Pizza"));
                %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
public String getMenu(String Category) throws SQLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Connection connection = Database.connectToDatabase();
    Statement st = connection.createStatement();
    String sql = "SELECT Name, Cost " +
                 "FROM MenuTable " +
                 "WHERE category = '" + Category + "';";
    //<% Order.inputIntoCtable(\""+rs.getString(0)+"\", 1);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    String categoryMenu = "";
    while (rs.next()) {
        categoryMenu += "<div class=\"menu-item\">"+ "\n"+
                    "<div class=\"menu-item-text\">"+ "\n"+
                        "<h3 class=\"menu-item-heading\">"+ "\n"+
                        "<button onClick = <% THE JAVA CODE %>"+
                            "<span class=\"menu-item-name\">"+rs.getString(1)+"</span>"+ "\n"+
                            "<span class=\"menu-item-price\">£"+rs.getString(2)+"</span>"+ "\n"+
                         "</button>"+
                        "</h3>"+ "\n"+
                    "</div>"+ "\n"+
                "</div>" +"\n";
    }
    
    return categoryMenu;
}
```

Comment: what do you want to happen when the button is clicked?  you should include it in the `getMenu(...)` method - (not another `<% java code %>`) - I think it should be JavaScript that handles the button click (Java code will not run there)

Comment: **I think it should be JavaScript that handles the button click (Java code will not run there)**

Comment: The way that you are doing it is wrong.  Get the data before displaying the JSP.  Put into the request or session.  Use JSTL to loop and construct the HTML in the JSP.  Use Javascript to handle actions on HTML elements

Comment: The `<button>` is not a JSP tag. So it can't execute a Java `<%%>` code. Better you remove it at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can define a JavaScript function, like:

```
function handleButtonClick(){
   alert( "btn clicked");
}
```

and then add the name of your function in the JSP, similar to this:

```
...
"<button onClick ='handleButtonClick()'>"+
"  <span class=\"menu-item-name\">"+rs.getString(1)+"</span><br/>"+ 
"  <span class=\"menu-item-price\">£"+rs.getString(2)+"</span><br/>"+ 
"</button>"+
...
```

Having said that, this is very old-school and outdated way of building dynamic web pages.  If you are doing it just to learn, it's ok but I would not recommend building anything other than a hobby page with this approach as there are much better ways to do it today.

For example, do not embed HTML in your Java code.  Build the HTML in the JSP and add the dynamic parts with JSTL tags (as suggested in the comments)